# Django save object to db if condition met

Tags: django

I'm trying to use django pre_save signal to write the instance into db if a specific condition is met.

How can I achieve this ? 
I'm having a function handler which is called by pre_save and I want to drop saving the instance if a condition is not met.

I want to abort the whole save chain.

Is it pre_save signal the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can raise an exception:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def pre_save_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # your logic
    if my_error:
        raise Exception('Aborting')
```

This should work, but keep in mind that this is supposed to be dealt with on your forms/serializer in your view, not in a signal

Comment: I don't want to raise an error. I want the flow to continue cleanly.
I've moved the logic into forms. I've overridden ModelForm's save method.

Comment: That should do. But overriding the save method should be your last option. You should try to validated it on the `clean` method